# Обращение к классу из другого класса

Tags: java, классы

Как заставить объявленный элемент menu в Main.java быть объявленным и в Menu.java , дабы слушатель сработал и при нажатии кнопки открылось новое окно?

P.S Это нужно для разгрузки кода, ибо в длинном коде я быстро теряюсь. И да, это не весь код, а только его небольшой кусок.

Main.java

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame Mainframe = new JFrame();
JPanel Mainpanel = new JPanel();

Mainframe.setSize(1050,700);
Mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Mainframe.add(Mainpanel);
Mainframe.setTitle("None");

Mainpanel.setLayout(null);

JButton menu = new JButton("Меню");
menu.setBounds(600,580,434,81);
Mainpanel.add(menu);


Mainframe.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Menu.java

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Menu {
    public Menu {
        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFrame frame_menu = new JFrame();
                frame_menu.setSize(250,250);
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Создать экземпляр класса `Menu` и присвоить полю этого класса необходимое значение. Теперь есть доступ к кнопке из обоих классов. `public class Menu {JButton menu;}` и `Menu men = new Menu(); men.menu = new JButton("Меню");`

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Это нужно вписывать в Menu.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы хотите организовать нечто похожее на ["разделения данных приложения, пользовательского интерфейса и управляющей логики на три отдельных компонента"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter). Даже если это не так и ваша цель несколько иная, мой ответ должен вам помочь... Наверное.

**Menu.java**

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Menu {
    public JButton menuButton;

    public Menu() {
    }

    public void addMenuActionListener() {
        this.menuButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame_menu = new JFrame();
                frame_menu.setSize(250,250);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu menu = new Menu();

        JFrame Mainframe = new JFrame();
        JPanel Mainpanel = new JPanel();

        Mainframe.setSize(1050,700);
        Mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Mainframe.add(Mainpanel);
        Mainframe.setTitle("None");

        Mainpanel.setLayout(null);

        JButton menuButton = new JButton("Меню");
        menuButton.setBounds(600,580,434,81);

        menu.menuButton = menuButton;
        menu.addMenuActionListener();

        Mainpanel.add(menuButton);
        Mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Теперь в классе `Menu` вы можете написать ещё несколько методов, которые будут взаимодействовать с кнопкой.

Comment: Ругается на переменную **menu** ,  `JButton menu = new JButton("Меню");` , которая уже была определена в `Menu menu = new Menu();`

Comment: Да, весьма резонно, надо поменять имя

Comment: И ещё ругается на _Non-Static field in a static context_ **menuButton** `Menu.menuButton = menu;`

Comment: @ZuchoK Как же невнимательно. Исправил. И дальше с методом

Comment: Во, теперь работает!